# KODI keeps crashing due to segfault

Tags: kodi

Kodi won't start due to seg fault. I'm running linux mint and I first noticed the problem after installing miniconda3 which I have since deleted but am still getting the error so it possibly isn't related. Here is the terinal error I'm getting:

```
graham@gilgamesh:~$ kodi
ERROR: Unable to create application. Exiting
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
find: ‘/home/graham/.cache/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/graham/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/graham/.dbus’: Permission denied
viCrash report available at /home/graham/kodi_crashlog-20190715_150028.log
```

And here is the contents of /home/graham/kodi_crashlog-20190715_150028.log

Any suggestions?

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: Mon Jul 15 15:00:28 EDT 2019
 Kodi Options:
 Arch: x86_64
 Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019
 Release: Linux Mint 19 (Tara)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
=====>  Core file: /home/graham/core (2019-07-15 15:00:28.302042652 -0400)
        =========================================
[New LWP 12230]
[New LWP 12229]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/kodi-x11'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:356
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f8eb2e35700 (LWP 12230))]

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f8ed0fce880 (LWP 12229)):
#0  0x00007f8ed0c11f85 in futex_abstimed_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, abstime=0x7ffe8951c740, expected=0, futex_word=0x559ea371b238) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:205
#1  __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x7ffe8951c740, mutex=0x559ea38aacf0, cond=0x559ea371b210) at pthread_cond_wait.c:539
#2  __pthread_cond_timedwait (cond=0x559ea371b210, mutex=0x559ea38aacf0, abstime=0x7ffe8951c740) at pthread_cond_wait.c:667
#3  0x0000559ea019f46b in ?? ()
#4  0x0000559ea0cc7c14 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000559ea0ba99b3 in ANNOUNCEMENT::CAnnouncementManager::~CAnnouncementManager() ()
#6  0x0000559ea0194e06 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000559ea080d03d in CApplication::~CApplication() ()
#8  0x0000559ea0164ff2 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000559ea0cf1e39 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f8ec9773041 in __run_exit_handlers (status=-1, listp=0x7f8ec9b1b718 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true, run_dtors=run_dtors@entry=true) at exit.c:108
#11 0x00007f8ec977313a in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:139
#12 0x00007f8ec9751b9e in __libc_start_main (main=0x559ea0122d00 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7ffe8951c998, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffe8951c988) at ../csu/libc-start.c:344
#13 0x0000559ea015a08a in _start ()

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f8eb2e35700 (LWP 12230)):
#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:356
#1  0x00007f8ec97be4cc in __GI__IO_default_xsputn (f=f@entry=0x559ea371ce40, data=<optimized out>, n=n@entry=94) at genops.c:404
#2  0x00007f8ec97bba33 in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x559ea371ce40, data=<optimized out>, n=94) at fileops.c:1287
#3  0x00007f8ec97af977 in __GI__IO_fwrite (buf=0x7f8eac000d00, size=94, count=1, fp=0x559ea371ce40) at iofwrite.c:39
#4  0x0000559ea05879ad in CLog::WriteLogString(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#5  0x0000559ea05880b6 in CLog::LogString(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&) ()
#6  0x0000559ea0ce4fa4 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000559ea056a9f0 in CThread::staticThread(void*) ()
#8  0x00007f8ed0c0b6db in start_thread (arg=0x7f8eb2e35700) at pthread_create.c:463
#9  0x00007f8ec985188f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
############# END STACK TRACE ###############

################# LOG FILE ##################

<feff>2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Starting Kodi (18.2 Git:20190422-f264356). Platform: Linux x86 64-bit
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Using Release Kodi x64 build
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Kodi compiled 2019-04-22 by GCC 7.3.0 for Linux x86 64-bit version 4.15.18 (266002)
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Running on Linux Mint 19, kernel: Linux x86 64-bit version 4.15.0-50-generic
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: FFmpeg version/source: 4.0.3-Kodi
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Host CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz, 12 cores available
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/kodi
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://xbmcbinaddons/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/addons
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/graham/.kodi/userdata
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://envhome/ is mapped to: /home/graham
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /home/graham/.kodi
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /home/graham/.kodi/temp
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://logpath/ is mapped to: /home/graham/.kodi/temp
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/kodi-x11
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Local hostname: gilgamesh
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: Log File is located: /home/graham/.kodi/temp/kodi.log
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104    INFO: loading settings
2019-07-15 15:00:26.254 T:140251368319104   ERROR: CProfileManager: error loading special://masterprofile/profiles.xml, Line 0
                                            Error document empty.
2019-07-15 15:00:26.255 T:140251368319104  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
2019-07-15 15:00:26.255 T:140251368319104   FATAL: unable to load profile


############### END LOG FILE ################

############ END Kodi CRASH LOG #############
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=229292). I just deleted `~/.kodi/userdata/profiles.xml` and now it works fine!